# Unable to catch exception from assert method using Respect Validation

Tags: php, slim, respect-validation

I'm using [Respect Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) to attempt to validate data sent via a POST request. In doing so I discovered an issue where an exception in the Respect Validation library is not being caught.

```
$postValidator = v::key('name', v::stringType()->length(3, 50))
                 ->key('email', v::email())
                 ->key('contact', v::phone())
                 ->key('message', v::stringType()->length(7, 1000));

try {
    $isValid = $postValidator->assert(['random' => 'thing']);
} catch(Exception $exception) {
    return $response->withJson([
        'success' => false
    ]);
}
```

Testing the following returns the following error:

```
All of the required rules must pass for { "random": "thing" }
```

Here I've used a generic `Exception` that should catch any exception that occurs within the `assert` method. But it appears it doesn't and I'm getting a generic Slim error, instead of a JSON response:

[image]

Any ideas why I cannot catch that exception?

The problem I am having is Respect Validation will throw an exception if a naughty users was to input postdata that the app can not handle. Personally I'd rather respect validation just ignore those, but it doesn't. So I want to catch the exception that Respect throws when a user passes undefined post data and return a response. Except, in the code above the exception isn't being caught.

Comment: Documentation says to use `assert()`, yet from testing it appears I need to use `validate()`. Docs state: `When something goes wrong, Validation can tell you exactly what's going on. For this, we use the assert() method instead of validate()`: https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/feature-guide/#informative-exceptions

Comment: Using `validate()` doesn't include the error details as the docs state. Now quite sure why it's not working with `assert()`

Comment: IIRC, Slim has its own Exception class which may be the reason you're not catching the Respect exception. Have you tried `catch(\Exception $exception)`? Using PHP's root exception class should catch any derived from it, regardless of namespace branch.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I encountered the same problem and this is how I resolved it. I hope someone might find the helpful. For me it worked as follows,

```php
$input = [ 
    'title' => 1
    'description' => "Validator test"
    'author' => "nipuna"
];

$postValidator = Valid::key('title',Valid::length(2,30)->stringType())
                    ->key('description',Valid::stringType())
                    ->key('author',Valid::intType()->length(1,2))
                    ->key('user',Valid::intType()->length(1,2));
try {
    $isValid = $postValidator->assert($input);
    // Do something with it
} catch (NestedValidationException $e) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode([
        'error' => $e->getMessages()
    ]);
}
```

The result was,

```json
{
    "error": {
        "title": "title must be of type string",
        "author": "author must have a length between 1 and 2",
        "user": "user must be present"
    }
}
```

The only change I've done is, changing the way I'm getting errors in the catch. You can catch the exception just by using `Exception` in the catch too as extended Exceptions would fall back to native PHP Exception. But `getMessages()` is a part of `NestedValidationException`. So using that would be appropriate in the catch.

So in your case since there are no matching keys in your array, it should display `{{key}} must be present`